# How do you change library location in R?

Tags: r, installation

Due to the new R 2.11 release, I want to implement Dirk's suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r).

So for that I am asking - How can I (permanently) change R's library path?  (The best solution would be one that can be run from within R)

Comment: Please see the 'R Installation and Admin manual' and/or `help(Startup)`; there are several options that are clearly documented. You have several environment variables you can set; and several options about where to set them. My previous answer provides one; you did not say why you do not want to or cannot use it. But all other options are clearly documented; the question has also been re-hashed dozens of times on r-help.

Comment: I have been look here - http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What_0027s-the-best-way-to-upgrade_003f  with no success. I'll check in that manual then.

Comment: o.k, using the example in the text, I get an error...  
Error: 16:10: unexpected '/'
16: R_LIBS=C:/

Comment: Yes, you need to protect strings with quotes

Comment: Thanks Dirk, actually - the error was because I didn't work with Renviron.site but instead used Rprofile.site  ("You live, you learn...")

Comment: Note that those files are (on all systems) inside the R 'tree' and will be replaced by the next version.  Consider user-local files, or system-wide environment variables.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I did - I'll publish what I wrote tomorrow, and would love for your feedback. Best, Tal

Comment: `help(Startup)` unfortunately does not document the new usage of .libPaths() as a function, probably the most practical way out in many cases. Nor does it give a pointer to .libPaths (?library does, though.)

Answer (score 37):

You can edit `Rprofile` in the `base` library (in `'C:/Program Files/R.Files/library/base/R'` by default) to include code to be run on startup. Append

```
########        User code        ########
.libPaths('C:/my/dir')
```

to `Rprofile` using any text editor (like Notepad) to cause R to add `'C:/my/dir'` to the list of libraries it knows about.

(Notepad can't save to Program Files, so save your edited Rprofile somewhere else and then copy it in using Windows Explorer.)

Answer (score 22):

This post is just to mention an additional option. In case you need to set custom R libs in your Linux shell script you may easily do so by

```
export R_LIBS="~/R/lib"
```

See [R admin guide](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Add_002don-packages) on complete list of options.

Answer (score 21):

I've used this successfully inside R script:

```
library("reshape2",lib.loc="/path/to/R-packages/")
```

useful if for whatever reason libraries are in more than one place.

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party but I encountered the same thing when I tried to get fancy and move my library and then had files being saved to a folder that was outdated:

```
.libloc <<- "C:/Program Files/rest_of_your_Library_FileName"
```

One other point to mention is that for Windows Computers, if you copy the address from Windows Explorer, you have to manually change the '\' to a '/' for the directory to be recognized.

Comment: .lib.loc is now defunct for R >= 2.0.0