# change r-library directory windows 8.1

Tags: r

Hello this is likely to be a silly question, sorry for that.

I want to change the library folder in Windows but I do not understand what is said in [the cran website](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html):

> You may also want to add command-line arguments at the end of the Target field (after any final double quote, and separated by a space), for example --sdi --max-mem-size=1G. You can also set environment variables at the end of the Target field, for example R_LIBS=p:/myRlib, and if you want to ensure that menus and messages are in (American) English, LANGUAGE=en.

When I set the R_LIBS variable in R with  `R_LIBS="C:/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0"` it doen't give any error but the folder path for the library does not change becuse when I type `require(package)` it is not found.

I saw  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698269/how-do-you-change-library-location-in-r-under-windows-xp) and it says it can be due to the R.profile. I don't know how to deal with the error, should I just remove R and install it from the beginning?

Comment: are you using an IDE such as RStudio or accessing R directly? (I have had similar problems on Windows but it was an RStudio problem)

Comment: RStudio, thank you for your interest, agstudy's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the environment variable R_LIBS in Windows ( not within R) to something like

```
R_LIBS=C:/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0
```

Restart R.

Note to set the environment variable you can use `setx` command:

1. Open a `cmd` console (command line console)
2. setx R_LIBS %R_LIBS%;C:/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0;