# error trying to install shinyapps

Tags: r, windows, installation, shiny

I am trying to install `shinyapps` from Github, but the installation fails.  Details from my R console are shown below. I'm using Rstudio under Windows 7.

I am a relative R and shiny novice. I think it may be due to the space in my path between "David" and "Hindley", but I don't know how to get round that.

```
> devtools::install_github("rstudio/shinyapps")
Downloading github repo rstudio/shinyapps@master
Installing shinyapps
"C:/Software/R-3.1.3/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/David  \   Hindley/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6dlMkN/devtoolsf6f032f40ee/rstudio-shinyapps-75c7269" \   --library="C:/Software/R-3.1.3/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'shinyapps' ...
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386 Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:\Users\David': Permission denied

*** arch - x64 Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:\Users\David': Permission denied

ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing 'C:/Software/R-3.1.3/library/shinyapps' Error: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I cleaned up the formatting and language, and picked some clearer tags to make it easier for the relevant people to find this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, on principle your library path shouldn't have spaces. Basically, you can try:

- Change your library path (recommended)
- Try `install.packages` as it should take care of spaces in the path
- Manually download and unzip `.tar.gz` and attempt to install from directory

Comment: Thanks.  How do I change the library path?

Comment: Just have a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698269/how-do-you-change-library-location-in-r) there is a number of ways you can do that.

Comment: Thanks.  Will look at those suggestions.