# Library is not writable

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have this issue during package installation in R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) on an Ubuntu machine:

```
install.packages("randomForest")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: just do `sudo R` if you are using terminal. I cant tell if this is a script to execute thought.

Comment: do NOT just sudo this. leads to all sorts of issues with read-write access.

Answer (score 70):

For R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) this problem should be dealt with since R suggests within the installation process a different path to store your R libraries. The installation looks like this: 
(Here 'random' is used as an example package)

```
install.packages('random')

Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("random") :
'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable

Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n) y

Would you like to create a personal library
~/R/pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2
to install packages into?  (y/n) y
```

So during the installation answering both questions with 'y' should install the package correctly.

**Update 18/01/19**

In case you don't want to store your R packages in an additional file:

As [Antoine-Sac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540919/library-is-not-writable/36696488#comment95292973_36696488) and [Robert TheSim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45036570/6015753) point out you can add yourself to the staff group in order to be able to write to 'site-library'. (Click on the names to see their important additions)

Before this update I mentioned in this comment the option of changing the permission of the folder 'site-library' using 'chmod o+w' in order to be able to write to it. Assuming security issues but unable to tell at the time I warned about it but have primarily been waiting for somone to clear this up. Antoine-Sac and Robert TheSim [have done so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540919/library-is-not-writable/36696488#comment95292973_36696488) in the meantime. Thanks!

Comment: You mention "possible downside."  What are possible downsides?  Can I muck up my R installation accidentally if I do this?

Comment: Are there downsides to saying yes to both questions?

Comment: Changing permissions funked up my installation somehow! It was not enough and I had to do a full reinstall as per [here](http://agent18.github.io/R-installation.html)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed your comments until now. @Stephen: To my knowledge answering both questions with yes doesn't cause any problems at all. A personal library will simply be created automatically. frank: Changing the permissions of the folder 'site-library' didn't lead to problems on my machine. Unfortunately I can't tell for other systems and as Thej Kiran mentions problems might occur. So the sure way is creating the library automatically.

Comment: Don't do that! Setting o+w allows any other user (which means any process running) to write to the site-library, which is a security concern. The site-library directory belongs to group staff. Simply add yourself to the staff group (on debian and related `sudo adduser <username> staff`, see the answer below for the more generic command) and you you can write to it. No need to change the permissions at all.

Answer (score 28):

If you are on Windows, you can run R (or RStudio) as an administrator.

Close your R, then go to the R or RStudio icon, right-click and "open as administrator". It works perfectly, all error messages while installing packages are gone forever.

Comment: thank you. Your answer helped me as you stated about elevating to administrator. I just relaunched the command editor with admin prevelage, then eveything went as charm. FYI, I am using a Windows machine, not Linux. I don't know if you can do the same on Linux

Comment: Running things with privilege is easy in Linux, and it is used often. To open RStudio with root privilege type `sudo rstudio` command in terminal.

Comment: You, sir, are a legend.

Comment: You deserve every possible thumbs-up m8!

Answer (score 25):

add yourself to the group called 'staff'

```
sudo usermod -a -G staff your_user_name
```

replace your_user_name with your login username, then logoff and relogin.

DO NOT use chmod 777 which is a breach of security and btw. a complete non-sense!!!

Comment: Yes this works perfectly fine - just need to log in and out of rstudio. Thanks for pointing out that `site-library` belongs to staff!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: This might be specific to the centos like distros and not generic enough

Comment: Does `whoami` provide me the `your_user_name` variable you are using?

Comment: You can also just do `sudo usermod -a -G staff $USER` and it will resolve the right username automatically.

Comment: the owner of that folder is root, not staff

Comment: Potentially dumb question: WHERE do you type in sudo usermod -a -G staff …? Command prompt? R terminal? R console? Elsewhere?

Comment: @Jade131621 in the terminal, it's a linux bash command.

Answer (score 23):

**The problem** is that the default install location is a place where you do not have write permissions.

**The solution** is to use an install location where you do have write permissions.

**Specifically**, I'd suggest using the following commands to create a personal library folder in a place that doesn't require special permissions and that will automatically be detected the next time you startup R:

```
dir.create(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"), recursive = TRUE)  # create personal library
.libPaths(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"))  # add to the path

install.packages("randomForest")  # install like always
library(randomForest)  # use library like always
```

The call to [`dir.create`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/files2) follows the suggestion in [this faq](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#I-don_0027t-have-permission-to-write-to-the-R_002d3_002e6_002e0_005clibrary-directory) to create a folder named according to `Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")`.  This is a good choice since it will be found on the next startup of R so you will be able to use `install.packages` and `library` without specifying special locations.  The [`.libPaths`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/libPaths) function call lets us avoid restarting R by immediately adding the new folder to the library path. The first two lines are only needed if you do not yet have a personal library created, but there is no harm in running them repeatedly.  After that, installing packages and using libraries can be done as usual.

Comment: I had the same problem in linux, and this was the answer which solved it. Thanks!.

Answer (score 22):

For someone who tried to use **`install.packages()` with multiple packages** like this:

```
install.packages("vcd","vcdExtra","plyr")
```

and got similar warning:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  'lib = "vcdExtra"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel) cancel
Error in install.packages : unable to install packages
```

You should **put the package names in a vector**:

```
install.packages(c("vcd","vcdExtra","plyr"))
```

as the second parameter in `install.packages()` is *lib*.

Comment: I had the same problem until I realized I should be wrapping the package names in c(). So, `install.packages(c("vcd","vcdExtra","plyr"))` should work

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer by adding your solution

Comment: `install.packages("vcd","vcdExtra","plyr")` should've been `install.packages(c("vcd","vcdExtra","plyr"))`, the second parameter in the `install.packages` is `lib`

Comment: @Ash, thank you for the explanation. I have removed other solution. Feel free to edit my answer further if needed :)

Comment: This worked for me on windows 10 , R 4.0.5

Comment: This is the expected way to install multiple packages at once, so It should work regardless of the OS, and version I believe :)

Comment: This is answers a question that the original question poster did not ask. I do not understand why this is the top answer for this question.

Comment: Hi Colin, because the warnings are similar, many end up finding the question while searching for a solution to the problem this answer solves for them. I thought It wouldn't harm anyone If I post the solution I figured worked for the problem I had at the time. If you wish, you are free to post a specific question and answer it with my answer and take the credit there :)

Answer (score 6):

It means exactly what it says. You don't have write permission in that folder. Either you need to [change the permissions for that folder](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions), or [change the R library location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2698269/2954547).

Comment: thank you sir..!  I have doubt in one more question.. I got the error while installing the rgl package in Rstudio.             install.packages("rgl")     i got  the error of                                Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License
     License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built.

Comment: Third option (see below): add yourself to the `staff` group which gives you permission to write in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OS windows 10 then maybe Ransomware protection is on. You need to disable that.

I was facing the same problem. I had the access to write. but suddenly it stopped. I couldn't install the packages. Disabling Ransomware protection worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The `"XX" is not writable` error can also mean that the library path you're providing does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo`  to Rscript code. I have same error fixed using `sudo Rscript filename.R`

Error

```
$ Rscript babynames.R 
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("babynames") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("babynames") : unable to install packages
Execution halted
```

Fix

```
$ sudo Rscript babynames.R 
[sudo] password for abhay: 
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘glue’, ‘utf8’, ‘fansi’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘magrittr’, ‘pillar’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’, ‘tibble’
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can try sudo chmod +777 #nameoflib
It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if rstudio is sandboxed it gives the "is not writable" warning.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to reproduce the Quarto book `mlr3book` in Ubuntu 22.04 because the package `MASS` requires R-4.2 instead of R-4.1 (the default). After uninstalling R-4.1 and installing R-4.2, I got this error that didn't get before with 4.1: `Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)`. I suspected that the settings for the local user library was removed.

My solution was accidental. I opened `RStudio` to see if I had the same problem installing packages as I had in the terminal; I installed one package successfully. So, I went back to my terminal, and now I don't get the error anymore.

I cannot explain exactly how RStudio fixed this but I assume it automatically sets up a local user library when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error message at:

```
renv::activate()
renv::restore()
```

Intrestingly `renv::activate()` did not set the library path correctly. So I suspect a bug in `rstudi/renv@v1.0.3`

Based on answer of @teichert I found a workaround as:

```
.libPaths(renv::paths$library())
renv::activate()
renv::restore()
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are using R with RStudio, rather than starting RStudio with tray icon, start Rstudio or R with command line using `sudo rstudio` or `sudo R`.

It will solve your problem for sure, it works for me. It requires `sudo` privilege to write something in installation directory.

Comment: It looks more reasonable to change permission on single directory than allowing an application to potentially nuke whole system

Comment: This also makes updating and uninstalling packages a real pain.

Comment: "with great power comes great responsibility": you don't want to use `sudo` this way, won't you? Fix the permissions on filesystem and/or change the location where to install the package. To an extent, use the [`$R_LIBS_USER`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html)

Answer (score -4):

You can change permission to 'site-library' and all included directories.

sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local/lib/R/site-library

Comment: This is probably quite unsafe!

Comment: What's so unsafe in make R library folder writable? I don't really understand why it's not writable in the first place. It's whole idea/design is for you to write libraries into it.