# Getting error , when i try running R from a linux box

Tags: r

helloworld.r

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
ds1 = data.frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
install.packages("caTools", dependencies=TRUE)
str(ds1)
```

output :

```
-bash-4.1$ ./helloworld.r
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)


 Warning in install.packages("caTools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  'lib = "/usr/lib64/R/library"' is not writable
  Error in install.packages("caTools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  unable to install packages
  Execution halted
```

Comment: '*"/usr/lib64/R/library"' is not writable*' - Well, there is your problem.

Comment: `sudo ./helloworld.r`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Library is not writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540919/library-is-not-writable)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run R with sudo

```
sudo R
```