# cannot update packages in rstudio Windows10

Tags: r, rstudio

I keep getting this message when I try to update or install packages:

lib= "C:/Users/Soren/OneDrive/R/win-library/3.5"' is not writable

[image]

p.s. I'm a newbie and cannot figure out how to set the libpath to NOT go to Onedrive

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, this issue was discussed here [link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540919/library-is-not-writable). Essentially you cannot write to that folder, so first close R and use Rstudio as administrator and try again. If that does not work and you have another place where you want to install packages then just specify it like this: `install.packages("mynewlibrary", lib = C:/path/to/new/writable/directory)`. I can't remember if the paths in windows are forward slash or double backslash though. Hope this helps you out

Answer (score 0):

`.libPaths('C:/Users/Soren/PathTo/Avoid/Stupid/OneDrive/R/win-library/3.5')`

or if you have some packages already installed in the OneDrive folder, to append:

`.libPaths(c('C:/Users/Soren/PathTo/Avoid/Stupid/OneDrive/R/win-library/3.5', .libPaths()))`