# Warning in install.packages 'path' is not writable R

Tags: r, directory, path, rstudio

I am unable to install any package due to the error mentioned in the title.

I attempt to run the following package :

```
install.packages("tseries")
```

However, I then receive the error:

```
Warning in install.packages  'lib = "C:/Users/santi/OneDrive/Documents/R"' is not writable :
```

Afterwards, I receive the following pop message:
[image]

I proceed to click "yes" bu then I get the following error:

```
Warning in install.packages   cannot create dir 'C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\file64444b1a3a3b', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I want to be clear that I am using my personal computer and all my settings are set to administrator and I have set all my premissions to my account to "Allow"

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Library is not writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540919/library-is-not-writable)

Comment: I think this might be an issue with writing into a cloud sync folder which is frequently locked up by OneDrive syncing. I would choose to host your R package library somewhere else on your computer.

Comment: I am unsure about that because I have had it in the cloud in the past and I had no issues.