# R package bizdays cannot be installed

Tags: r, bizdays

I have been using `bizdays` package for a long time and since I changed my window installation recently I had to install all of the packages for R. The only package that is not installed is `bizdays`. The documentations appear to show this package should be still on CRAN, but I cannot find it or install it. Is there any way to somehow install it back?

This is the error I am getting:

```
install.packages("bizdays")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

So it seems the package got installed, and when I try to use it this is the error thrown:

```
library(bizdays)
```

> Error in library(bizdays) : there is no package called ‘bizdays’

Comment: Where is the error? Looks like it got installed into your personal library.

Comment: It gives me that message, but the library does not show up and when I use inside my R script I get an error message, I will update the post

Comment: What do you see if you run `.libPaths()`?

Comment: Package names are case sensitive. Is the package named “bizdays” or “Bizdays”?

Comment: @zephryl I see two results: [1] "C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library"

Comment: I have heard of people having problems installing packages into OneDrive. Perhaps try the advice here and in the referenced prior answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468370/how-to-get-r-to-stop-downloading-r-packages-to-onedrive

Comment: You may need to update R to =>4.0

Comment: I'm using 4.2.2. You can check with `R.version`. Needing to update R is a fairly common cause of package install problems. Your path is to 3.6.2

Comment: upgrading to version 4.2.2 resolve dthe problem, but RStudion needed to be relaunched

Comment: Awesome! I'll move the comments to answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to update R to =>4.0
You can check with R.version.
Needing to update R is a fairly common cause of package install problems, as packages can use new R features. You will need to restart RStudio