# Possible Bug: R CMD check fails on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS when using nlme

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04, nlme

Using `devtools::check()` gives the following error message:

```
R CMD check results
1 error  | 0 warnings | 0 notes
checking whether package ‘abc’ can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
See ‘/tmp/RtmpSpjP2M/abc.Rcheck/00install.out’ for details.
```

The contents of `/tmp/RtmpSpjP2M/abc.Rcheck/00install.out` are

```
* installing *source* package ‘abc’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error : package ‘nlme’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘abc
* removing ‘/tmp/RtmpSpjP2M/abc.Rcheck/abc’
```

Even re-installation of `nlme` with the following code

```
install.packages("nlme", type = "source")
```

gives the same error. Any solution, please. Thanks

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8      
 [2] LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
[12] LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] nlme_3.1-137

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1  tools_3.5.1     yaml_2.2.0     
[4] grid_3.5.1      lattice_0.20-35
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3974549/1412059

Comment: Thanks @Roland for your comment.  `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)` gives the message  `Warning: package 'nlme' in library '/usr/lib/R/library' will not be updated`. Any thoughts.

Comment: First try: Restart R before updating packages.

Comment: I restarted R before updating packages but still get the same error (@Roland). Interestingly I do have nlme_3.1-137 which is the latest version. I also deleted the directory nlme and reinstalled it but still the same error.

Comment: maybe disable lazyloading from DESCRIPTION for now? same error if u run R CMD check from shell?