# Error in library(sp) : there is no package called 'sp'

Tags: r

The `sp` package was installed using **RStudio** (through CRAN) but when **R** evaluates the code:

```
library(sp)
```

It throws an error

```
Error in library(sp) : there is no package called 'sp'
```

I noticed that it works for R versions `4.*` but does not work for versions `3.*`. What could be causing this?

Comment: Different environments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After I upgrade my R version, how can I easily reinstall all the packages that were installed in the old version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974488/after-i-upgrade-my-r-version-how-can-i-easily-reinstall-all-the-packages-that-w)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/19407092/680068 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/47395807/680068

Answer (score 0):

If you first time to use 'sp', install.... :)

```
install.packages("sp")
library(sp)
```