# R: Updating .libPaths() on Ubuntu

Tags: r

I am trying to follow advice [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Managing-libraries) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133394/migrating-r-libraries), to update the location where R looks for installed packages. I have updated the variable `.Library.site` in the `/etc/R/Rprofile.site` file to include the location of the intended R package library directory:

```
Sys.setenv(".Library.site" = "~/AppData/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/")
```

However, when I start up R, and do a `.libPaths()` the location is not appended to the list of library locations. Why?

Answer (score 5):

Three answers:

1. Your approach is wrong. `.libPath()` is an R function, not an environment variable.  What you do above above cannot work.
2. Per a consensus with (some members of) R Core, I have been setting the path to three location since circa 2003 for Debian / Ubuntu. That is done below `/etc/R/` and you probably saw it.
3. The easiest to set a per-user directory would be via `R_LIBS_USER` which I typically comment-out as I like as users on a machine to have consistent paths. You can set it either in the global `Renviron`, or in the global `Renviron.site` (better) or in `~/.Renviron` (probably best).
   You do that via `R_LIBS_USER="~/AppData/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/"`.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Safe to assume that `~/.Renviron` not created by default, and that if one does not exist, can create one?

Comment: Also, not clear on your 1. & 2. If I do successfully change the location of the package directory, I should be able to retrieve it from within R using `libPaths()`, right? Re. 2. when you say that you set the location in 3 places you mean that this can be achieved using one of the `*.site` files in the `/etc/R` directory, right? Apologies for the confusion, new to manipulating environment variables for R.

Comment: Huh? I am asking a follow-on question about your consensus with the R core members. Unlikely that is discussed in `help(Startup)`?

Comment: I am sorry but I already gave you the directory.  If that wasn't specific enough, try `cat /etc/R/Renviron` and *what those values mean is described in the help page I just pointed you to*.