# Migrating R library from /usr/lib/R/library to a custom library

Tags: r, linux, package, installation

All the R packages installed on this Linux machine are installed in `/usr/lib/R/library`. I want to move these packages to another location, such as `/home/username/.R_libs`. I not only want to install packages in this new location, but I want to migrate all the previously installed packages to that location.

The output of `.libPaths()` is:

```
[1] "/home/username/.R_libs" "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

However, if I just move all the packages, like so:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/R/library/* /home/username/.R_libs/
```

R cannot start anymore as it seems unable to find the base package.

As for environment variables, `$R_LIBS` is set to `/home/username/.R_libs`, while `$R_HOME` and `$R_LIBS_USER` are unset in the shell. However, for some reason:

```
> Sys.getenv("R_LIBS")
[1] "/home/username/.R_libs"
> Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
[1] "/usr/lib64/R"
> Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")
[1] "~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4"
```

Note that `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4` does not exist and I do not want to create it, I want to only use `/home/username/.R_libs`.

In short, I want that from now on R will only consider `/home/username/.R_libs` and always install libraries to (or read libraries from) that location without asking for confirmation or additional options.

The best option, if I understood this correctly, would probably to move only the non-base packages, so the packages that were manually installed. Is this possible? Can this be done?
Note that I'd prefer not to have to uninstall then reinstall all packages,

Comment: `export R_LIBS="/home/username/.R_libs"`

Comment: @Masoud Sorry, I do not to understand. `R_LIBS` is already set to the folder that I want the packages to be in, namely `/home/username/.R_libs`

Comment: You can run this within R `.libPaths("/home/username/.R_libs")`

Comment: @Masoud `.libPaths()` already returns `[1] "/home/username/.R_libs" "/usr/lib/R/library"`. What should the difference be?

Comment: You need to remove the `/usr/lib/R/library/` from that, right?

Comment: No, I do not think so. I do not see why. The library I want is first anyway, so the second library should not matter. I want to migrate packages from the second library to the first.

Comment: What I meant was you want to set it as default. But let's put our discussion on hold. I will post an answer after I made sure that it'll work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change library location in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698269/how-do-you-change-library-location-in-r) Read the last one. I just edited `.RProfile` and it worked. Notice that I kept the copy of that in the default location.

Comment: @Masoud If I just add the line, new packages will be installed there. Which is OK. But If I try to update the older packages, they will still be in `/usr/lib/R/library/`. I do not want that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133394/migrating-r-libraries

Comment: @Masoud This basically suggest to re-install all installed packages, which is something I'd like to avoid. Surely it can be done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by listing all packages that have `Priority` NA or "Recommended" in R, and moving only that with a bash script. This will ignore all the base R packages that R seems to require being stored where they currently are. So from R create a text file to read from the bash script:

```
ip <- installed.packages(lib.loc="/usr/lib/R/library/")[ , "Priority"]
write.table(installed.packages(lib.loc="/usr/lib/R/library/")[is.na(ip) | ip=="recommended", 1], file="ip.txt", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Note that you will need to change `/usr/lib/R/library/` to the correct folder you want to copy from.

Then run this bash script (remember set your own target dir, stored in the `output` variable, and your username, stored in the `user` variable):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
{
input="/usr/lib/R/library/"
output="/home/username/.R_libs/"
user="username"
packages="ip.txt"

for p in $(cat ${packages})
do
    if [ -e ${input}/${p} ]; then
        echo Moving package ${p}
        mv ${input}/${p} ${output}/${p}
    else
        echo Package ${p} is not present in ${input}
    fi
done
echo Changing perimssions...
chown -R ${user} .R_libs/*
echo All done!
}
```

Everything should be moved correctly.

Comment: Glad you found your solution.