# Move installed R packages from user library to system library

Tags: r

I have my R packages spread over multiple directories, both user-specific and system-wide:

```
r$> .libPaths()                                            
[1] "/home/user/R/custom_lib"                     
[2] "/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2"
[3] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                       
[4] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                             
[5] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

I'd like to move all packages to the system directory `/usr/lib/R/library`, and I was wondering if I can just move the folders, or will that create problems? Alternatively, how would I go about it?

Comment: I'm not adding an answer right now because this isn't really an answer to the question but - why exactly do you want to do this and are you the only person using that device?

Comment: As a small off-the-cuff response though - I don't think moving the folders corresponding to the other installed packages into one of the other library folders would negatively impact R in any way. It might make some packages "installed" for other users on the system but that's probably one of the only issues you might have within R itself.  The main issue is just package management - the system itself has a package manager and you're writing stuff into what is essentially the system's territory.  Is there a problem with this? Not really but it could get messy later on. I just don't recommend.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7133394/7758804, https://stackoverflow.com/q/31707941/7758804, [r move packages from user to system library site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+move+packages+from+user+to+system+library+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1RXQR_enUS982US982&sxsrf=ALiCzsa11libFA0yzf-ZUZMte_dBRZahdw:1657652446685&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRpPvJhPT4AhXoITQIHcCOCXQQrQIoBHoECC0QBQ&biw=2560&bih=1335&dpr=1)

Comment: @ Dason The reason for moving all libraries to the same folder is because having some system-wide and some user-specific tend to create issues when updating. If I run `update.packages()`  in R as user, I am unable to update system directories. If I run R as super user, I am unable to update user libraries. This issue is further amplified by some packages installed in user directory have dependencies installed system wide and vice-a-versa. This results in having to run `update.packages()` multiple times as my regular user and as super user, and some has to be reinstalled.