# How to upgrade R in ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have R 2.12.1 installed in my ubuntu, and I'd like upgrade to lastest version 2.15, how can achieve that ? Thanks

Comment: this is probably relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/279088/installing-the-latest-r-version-2-13-0-on-ubuntu-11-04

Comment: The R guide for this is here: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

Comment: Shouldn't this question have been moved to askubuntu.com instead of closing it down?

Comment: Easy steps here : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2

Comment: Updating Adam Erickson's link: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html instructions are for R >= 4.1

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Since R is already installed, you should be able to upgrade it with this method. First of all, you may want to have the packages you installed in the previous version in the new one,so it is convenient to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r/22989094#22989094). Then, follow the instructions from [here](http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/)

1. Open the `sources.list` file:

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Add a line with the source from where the packages will be retrieved. For example:

   ```
    deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ version/
   ```

   Replace `https://cloud.r-project.org` with whatever [mirror](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) you would like to use, and replace
   `version/` with whatever [version](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) of Ubuntu you are using (eg, `trusty/`, `xenial/`, and so on). If you're getting a "Malformed line error", check to see if you have a space between `/ubuntu/` and `version/`.
3. Fetch the secure APT key:

   ```
    gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
   ```

or

```
    gpg --hkp://keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

4. Add it to keyring:

   ```
    gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
5. Update your sources and upgrade your installation:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
6. Install the new version

   ```
    sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
   ```
7. Recover your old packages following the solution that best suits to you ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r/22989094#22989094)). For instance, to recover all the packages (not only those from CRAN) the idea is:

-- copy the packages from `R-oldversion/library` to `R-newversion/library`, (do not overwrite a package if it already exists in the new version!).

-- Run the R command `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)`.

Comment: Hello Ananda and others, I would love to include some of these solutions into the installr package: https://github.com/talgalili/installr/

Are any of you willing to pitch it?

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218708/installing-latest-version-of-r-base) worked

Comment: sudo su
echo "deb http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade

Comment: Note that this method will upgrade many other things besides R, which may not be what you want to do.

Comment: See my answer for a general way to update `R` on `debian` (on which `Ubuntu` is based): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r

Comment: Hi, just to follow up on that answer. For me, seems that the website from step 2 is down. I used another one : http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/. The line that I added into the source.list file is : **deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ bionic-cran35/**

Comment: Using the short ID for the key downloaded the spoofed key for me ("Totally Legit Signing Key"). See https://dev.gnupg.org/T4136 for details and update your answer with full key ID.

Comment: I am told that apt-key is deprecated ! Can you update?