# R: how to install this package?

Tags: r

I am trying to install the fpc package. According to

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Density-Based_Clustering

it's easy: just type install.packages("fpc", dependencies = TRUE)

I did that. But after 10-15 minutes of downloading whatever and thousands of lines flushing down my screen, RStudio did not react anymore.

Now I'm trying to install without dependencies = TRUE and get this error:

ERROR: dependencies ‘mclust’, ‘flexmix’ are not available for package ‘fpc’

Then I tried to do install.packages("mclust")

but I get this:

package ‘mclust’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)

Why can I not just install that package fpc? It seems to be quite prominent, so why is it so complicated to install it?

Comment: Upgrade R to version 3.something, then we can talk.

Comment: i did apt-get remove r-base and then I reinstalled it via apt-get install r-base. why am I not up-to-date ?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10476798/1270695

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade R to ver 3.x and You can install fpc from menubar on Rstudio

Choose `Tools >> Install Package >>` then type "fpc"

It will then download automatically.

I'm using Rstudio ver 0.98.1002 and R ver 3.1.2