# How to upgrade IRKernel in Ubuntu?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04, jupyter-irkernel

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, while working R in JupyterNotebook (without Anaconda), the IRKernel is reading the R version 3.4. For using some packages like cowplot it is necessary to have at least version 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, two steps should be taken:

1. **Update R**. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272149/update-r-version-from-3-0-3-to-3-1-2) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1) answers were a guideline.
2. **Update IRKernel**. The offical IRKernel [instructions](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/#linux-panel) for Linux were useful.

Next, is described the complete procedure

## 1. Add Key to server

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

## 2. Add Entry to sources.list

```
echo 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Depending on the linux you're using you should change, for example, bionic by xenial or cosmic, check out https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

## 3. Update Programs

According to the instructions in the above link, we should do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

## 4. Update /.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir

type R in the console and follow the next steps according to this [link](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/#linux-panel)

```
# In the console
R
# Inside R
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'IRkernel'), type = 'source')
getRversion() # to verify the new R version
IRKernel::installspec()
```

This should show the following message:

```
[InstallKernelSpec] Removing existing kernelspec in /home/user_name/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
[InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec ir in /home/user_name/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
```

As a final remark, you should remove the older version of R, which you can find in ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library, where you will now have two directories with two different versions or R (remove the older one).