# How to install R 3.1.2 on Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux, r, linux-mint

I have installed the latest version of Linux Mint (17.1) in my computer. I installed R version 3.0.2. However, when I try to install the package xslsx, or dplyr, the system says that these packages are unavailable for the R version I have, and that the shall be installed on the R 3.1.2 version. 've been trying to upgrade R from all the possible means but I haven't had a sucessful result. Is anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Please read the [corresponding README.html on the CRAN "debian" directory](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian/) which has everything you need to know.

Answer (score 10):

Follow the instructions posted here: [How to upgrade R in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu)

Note that Linux Mint 17.1 relies upon the Ubuntu Trusty package base, so you will need to use `trusty/` as the Ubuntu version.  Also, make sure to use the command `sudo apt-get upgrade r-base` at the end of the procedure, not just `sudo apt-get upgrade`, otherwise R won't be upgraded.

Your question may be considered off-topic, but it can be helpful to other Mint users.

Comment: How do you know that Linux Mint 17.1 relies on the trusty package base? How can I check this for my version?

Comment: This approach will not give you the latest version, just the latest version in the repository. For example (as of this writing) it thinks 3.2.2 is the latest, but 3.2.4 was just released.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this will help, your question helped me alot... Note that Linux mint is based on ubuntu trusty...

```
sudo su
echo "deb http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9}
sudo apt-get upgrade r-base
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to install properly from the `tar.gz` file linked [from the main R page](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/). I download it, I run `./configure` `make`, and it installs to my Downloads folder. Couldn't figure out how to install it properly elsewhere (must be easy, but I'm green on these things -- advice appreciated), and RStudio, e.g., doesn't know to look in my Downloads folder for the current version (also probably not the most robust approach).

Instead, I was able to grab the last `r-base-dev` `.deb` file from [`trusty` here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/)/[`xenial` here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial/), which handles installation automatically.

---

R versions 3.5+ have changed directories:

- [trusty](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty-cran35/)
- [xenial](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial-cran35/)

Answer (score 0):

Version specific installation using source code is much different than the installation using YUM or APT. It depends on OS version and the number of dependencies that need to be met for the installation to complete successfully. I have documented the installation of R 3.3.3 on SLES11 SP3 in http://hashprompt.blogspot.com/2017/06/installation-of-r-on-suse-linux.html Hope that it might help you install on linux systems.