# How to upgrade Rstudio on Linux Mint?

Tags: r

How to upgrade (not install new) R-studio on Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela?

These commands are correct?

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base.
```

Comment: Have your tried these commands and got error? Try them, see if they are correct.

Comment: OP is right to be careful before trying `sudo` commands if he doesn't understand them. Try it and see what happens is usually good advice, but not so with `sudo`...

Comment: Oh, by the way, I misread the question. This has nothing to do with upgrading RStudio, the IDE. It's about upgrading R, the statistical software. You should understand the difference between both. Upgrading RStudio is a matter of clicking the Help tab, then Check for updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux Mint 17.3, I personally just use the link from the RStudio website whenever I want to update:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

I use the [.deb link](https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb) for Ubuntu/64 bit (Mint is built over Ubuntu).

The commands you are trying to run suggest you're trying to upgrade *R*, not *RStudio* (an IDE for programming in R)...

For upgrading R itself, I follow my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35993894/3576984), which is basically to grab a .deb file for *R* from the RStudio website [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/).

Comment: I have downloaded the file and what I have to do for updating Rstudio?

Comment: @Oktu opening the .deb file automatically opens the Package Installer GUI utility, and I can just hit "Install Package". Simple as that...

Answer (score 0):

The R version in the default system repositories is a few minors behind. You have to make it explicit that you want to get R from a more up-to-date source.

You should add the following line:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, as described at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#installation.
(`trusty` is the nickname of the ubuntu version Mint 17 is based on (Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr))

Then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` at the command line should update R to the current version (3.4 as of today).

Comment: trying to understand: the first command is: sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list and then deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/ or it's the whole command?

Comment: It's either: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` then you add the `deb ...` line by hand once gedit is opened, then save and close. Or you could directly do `echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list` instead of `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`