# R 3.5 is not available for linux

Tags: r

It seems that as of April 28, 2018 the R 3.5 is not available for Linux in any of the mirrors. The latest r-base-core is for 3.4.4, see the image below from one of the mirrors. Meanwhile I was able to install R 3.5 for Windows. 
Do you know the reason why the latest R is not available for Linux?

[image: snapshot of the r mirror showing the latest r]

Comment: official repositories may not update for several weeks or more. install directly from R rather than relying on these if you want the latest.

Comment: e.g. I use this as a reference for Linux Mint. you'll have to fine tune this to your own system's particulars https://stackoverflow.com/q/28413507/3576984

Comment: An RPM for 3.5.0 is available for OpenSuse Linux 42.3, but I am going to wait a couple of weeks to install it.

Comment: thanks @MichaelChirico, it is clear now. I will wait until repos get the 3.5 uploaded. The make workflow seems a bit complicated :)

Comment: R 3.5.0 is available for Debian from CRAN.

Comment: @MichaelChirico That is actually the wrong advice. If it weren't for the binary change, we'd have binaries up in a _day or two_ as we usually. I build on release day, Michael follows the same or next day and a day later the CRAN mirrors have them.  Works reliably, and I updated dozens of R releases that way.  Now, for 3.5 it is harder (see my answer).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Do you know the reason why the latest R is not available for Linux?

Because we are volunteers.

Moreover, R 3.5 **breaks** the binaries of R 3.4.* and older so we have to rebuild **everything** first.  That is work in progress (for what is mirrored at CRAN).

For Debian proper, I of course uploaded the new packages the morning of the release (as you can see in the [ChangeLog](https://sources.debian.org/src/r-base/3.5.0-1/debian/changelog/)) but we are now in a so-called transition where all packages need to be rebuild (which you can monitor via [this tracker](https://release.debian.org/transitions/html/r-base-3.5.html)).

I am thinking of making interim packages available somewhere else. But I would have to find the time to build them first too.

*Edit:* I expanded a little [in this r-sig-debian mailing list post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2018-April/002829.html).

*Edit 2:* Please see the update status described [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2018/06/11#r_3_5_0_deb_update) (and same text [here](http://rubuntu.netlify.com/post/2018-06-11-r-3.5-on-debian-and-ubuntu-update/)).

Comment: Would almost suggest bolding the word volunteers... often seems lost on some

Comment: Thank you ever so much Dirk Eddelbuettel and all **volunteer** R developers/contributors that make users life easier. In industry we often forget how this is done, sorry for that.

Comment: Well, there [is now a mechanism](https://www.r-consortium.org/) to have industry contribute, and I did get my (previous) employer to pay for two years ...  Then again, that machine could be more well-oiled and do more things to help us actual volunteers on the ground, but that is a different story.

Comment: If I recall correctly, R 3.5 became available in Arch as early as a week after the release.

Comment: I made it available for Debian the day of the release, but only in the `experimental` branch as there is more to this due to binary changes.

Comment: `this tracker` link is broken

Comment: Yes, because the transition finished; see the [package page for r-base-core](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=r-base-core) showing 3.5.1 (subsequent release) in _testing_.