# R: Can't install devtools package

Tags: r

I try to install the devtool package with the command

```
install.packages('devtools')
```

I get the following output:

```
ERROR: dependency âxml2â is not available for package ârversionsâ
* removing â/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rversionsâ
ERROR: dependency ârversionsâ is not available for package âdevtoolsâ
* removing â/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/devtoolsâ

The downloaded source packages are in
    â/tmp/RtmprD4FpZ/downloaded_packagesâ
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("devtools") :
 installation of package ârversionsâ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("devtools") :
 installation of package âdevtoolsâ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I add these missing dependencies? Or what am I doing wrong?

My platform / version details:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the error messages (and I edit the UTF-8 away here):

> ERROR: dependency `xml2` is not available for package `rversions`
>
> ERROR: dependency `rversions` is not available for package `devtools`

and check the respective CRAN pages for [rversions](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rversions/index.html) and [xml2](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/xml2/index.html) to see that the latter has

> Depends:  R (≥ 3.1.0)

whereas you have

> R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

So in short: either upgrade R to a current versions, or stick with the (outdated) support packages that match your (outdated) R version.

Comment: I just found out how to upgrade my R installation on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu. Now I'm on R version 3.2.3 BUT I get the same error again when calling install.packages('devtools'). Can you help me? I'm new to R...

Comment: Please subscribe to and post on the r-sig-debian list.  We need more detail _as all this works for all of us_ on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: That page is outdated. Just read the [README itself](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu).