# updating R on linux (ubuntu) when an R script is running

Tags: r, linux, upgrade

I am planning to upgrade `R` on my linux server but I have started some long `R` scripts that i would not like to interrupt some time ago (they run for days). can I go through with the update whilst they are still running or is it impossible/not advisable?

I was planning to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu).

Comment: so, i went ahead with the update whilst the scripts were still running and it seemingly didn't affect them (they are still churning away).