# How to easily switch R versions on rstudio ubuntu based?

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio

I need to install a package that gives the following error so I am looking for a solution to that. The first approach is looking at ways to chose the right R version. [image]

Should I spend some more time on this or there are other approaches to overcome this issue?

Comment: Changing the R version wont install automatically an older version of said package. To install the specific version of a package you need the URL to it. Check out this: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages. Changing R version can be useful to avoid some troubles regarding package version and R version (which in my experience, is not common).

Answer (score 3):

For this package you need R (≥ 3.5.0), so R 3.4.4 is not sufficient for standard installation.

Check on the [cran website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/index.html) of the package  for further information.

For upgrading R on ubuntu check [here (old link!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu)

Edit: wibeasley mentioned a new link in the commentary for updating R 3.5.0 on Ubuntu. 
Check [the new link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031597/r-3-5-0-for-ubuntu)

Comment: More Ubuntu installation information for R ≥3.5.0: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031597/r-3-5-0-for-ubuntu.  Some settings have changed since that 2nd link above was written in 2012.