# I meet some troubles when I Updating R on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I want to update R from 3.4.4 to 3.5 on ubuntu. I follow this [How to upgrade R in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu?newreg=2f20875829024f9eb0a05e06a14abde1) ,but always meet some troubles

my try:

1、su

2、vi /etc/apt/sources.list and add 
deb https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/ xenial/

3、gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9

4、gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -

5、sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade   # meet some troubles

6、apt-get install r-base-dev  # also meet some troubles

```
Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nebc/bio-linux/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 404  Not Found

W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The followin   g signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PU    BKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
W: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not     signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potential    ly dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta    ils.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository     'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support archit    ecture 'i386'
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nebc/bio-linux/ubuntu xenial Release    ' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potential    ly dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta    ils.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nebc/bio-linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/m    ain/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used     instead.
x/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found^C-linu
```

```
root@omnisky:~# sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
r-base-dev is already the newest version (3.4.4-1xenial0). # why?
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
```

Comment: You're getting errors and warnings about `http://ppa.launchpad.net/nebc/bio-linux/ubuntu`, which looks like a separate repository that you've added in the past. These errors don't seem to be related to the CRAN repository.

Comment: How to solve this problem？（*＾-＾*）

Comment: Read https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html and pay close attention to the entry you need to add in your sources.list

Comment: Thank you. (*^▽^*)The problem has been solved.