# How to optimaly upgrade RStudio and R and keep project files and all setup (Windows machine)?

Tags: r

Many people use R and RStudio and they need to keep up with upgrades.

If one wants all RStudio projects to be "remembered". Is is possible? A seamless upgrade of both....

Should one first install new R version and then install RStudio into the same folder. (what is the best order of steps?)

Comment: This is unfortunately not an option within my company. Painless remote desktop solutions for linux are also a problem. (maybe just lack of knowledge, if it comes with Ubuntu then great).

Comment: (Yes, Debian based-systems permitted that since the start. That's how sysadmin work scales. A real package managers is a treasure.)

Answer (score 15):

Updating RStudio is no problem. You just go to Help > Check updates in the menu, and RStudio will take care of the rest. It also recognizes the latest installed R version on your computer, so just installing the new R should suffice for that. Note that project files are saved on your computer, and can of course be opened with the new version of RStudio you installed.

Regarding keeping the settings for your R version, see eg:

[Painless way to install a new version of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Gabor Grothendieck has a package 'batchfiles' [on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/batchfiles/) as well as [in CRAN's extra directory](http://cran.r-project.org/contrib/extra/batchfiles/) which does this.