# Can't install packages (Windows)

Tags: r

An attempt to install a package in R results in a typical error message:

```
install.packages("plotrix")
## Installing package into ‘C:/Users/nevs/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
## (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
## package ‘plotrix’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
## Warning in install.packages :
## package ‘plotrix’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

This message popped up for every package tried. Please suggest a solution or an an alternate way to install packages to R in windows.
System information:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2013                        
month          09                          
day            25                          
svn rev        63987                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
nickname       Frisbee Sailing
```

Comment: You probably need to update your version of R to the most recent release

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/) is about updating R from R on windows using the `installr` package.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Updating R from 3.0.2 to 3.1.0 solved the issue.
For more information on how to update R using Rstudio, refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656699/update-r-using-rstudio).
Source of this error is still unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but i recently update the app.
Sorry i am new to the programming environment of `R`

```
install.packages("plotrix")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/schal/OneDrive/ΞΞ³Ξ³ΟΞ±Ο†Ξ±/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
installing the source package ‘plotrix’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plotrix_3.6-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 224774 bytes (219 KB)
downloaded 219 KB

* installing *source* package 'plotrix' ...
** package 'plotrix' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
cannot open file 'C:/Users/schal/OneDrive/N3N3ON1ON1/R/win-library/3.3/plotrix/DESCRIPTION': Invalid argument
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'plotrix'
* removing 'C:/Users/schal/OneDrive/ΞΞ³Ξ³ΟΞ±Ο†Ξ±/R/win-library/3.3/plotrix'
Warning in install.packages :
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\schal\OneDrive\ΞΞ³Ξ³ΟΞ±Ο†Ξ±\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\schal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMbuRmt/downloaded_packages/plotrix_3.6-3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘plotrix’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\schal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMbuRmt\downloaded_packages’

 > version
           _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.1                         
year           2016                        
month          06                          
day            21                          
svn rev        70800                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
nickname       Bug in Your Hair
```