# Error: could not find function "distinct" when using dplyr library for R on Windows 7

Tags: r, dplyr, versions

I'd like to get the unique values from a column in a dataframe.  With the R package dplyr, it should be possible.

[image]

This `distinct(select(dataframe, column))` works great on my Mac. In RStudio on Windows 7 I encounter this:

[image]

when I run this R code:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
```

[image]

```
unique_values <- distinct(select(df, X1))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Please check if `dplyr::distinct(select(df, X1))` works? –  akrun

Of course - here is the console output:

[image]

**EDIT**

I've not used distinct, but perhaps unique would work for you? `unique(df$X1)` –  NPE

It does work, and it's concise too! I would still like to understand this dplyr error...

[image]

**EDIT**

Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` instead. –  Roland

[image]

**EDIT**

some comments note that `dplyr_0.2` version is old. `install.packages("dplyr")` gets a CRAN link to the old package.  Now to figure out how to manually install `dplyr_0.3.0.2`.

[image]

Comment: Please check if `dplyr::distinct(select(df, X1))` works?

Comment: I've not used `distinct`, but perhaps [`unique`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html) would work for you? `unique(df$X1)`

Comment: You give a lot of superfluous info. Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` instead.

Comment: Did you `library(dplyr)`?

Comment: Yes.  I should show that!  Editing question

Comment: Your `dplyr` version is very old, I'd suspect that maybe `distinct` wasn't there at the time

Comment: `distinct` is in 0.3.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Old `R` means old `dplyr` means no `distinct()` function.

To fix this, install the latest version of R:

1. go to http://www.r-project.org
2. click on 'CRAN'
3. then choose the CRAN site that you like. I like Kansas: http://rweb.quant.ku.edu/cran/
4. click on 'Download R for X' [where X is your operating system]
5. follow the installation procedure for your operating system
6. restart RStudio
7. rejoice

source: this very nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17625368/1732222)

Then run the command `install.packages("dplyr")` in the RStudio Console.

Now you can create a dataframe and use the `distinct()` function to get the unique values from one of its columns:

```
library(dplyr)

# create a dataframe with some values
df <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
df

# select a column from that dataframe and get a list of the unique values
unique_values <- distinct(select(df, X1))
unique_values
```

In the console you should see:

[image]

Thanks to [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg) and [Richard Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/richard-scriven) for pointing our that dplyr-0.2 is old and lacks the `distinct()` function.  This line of thinking led to the answer.