# Updating R version of JupyterLab

Tags: python, r, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using R in Jupyterlab with Anaconda .I need to update my R version of Jupyterlab. The r-base version of Anaconda is 4.1.1, but when I write `version` to Jupyter cell, it says my R version is 4.0.3. How can i update it 4.1.1 ?
Thank you.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating R that is used within IPython/ Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341820/updating-r-that-is-used-within-ipython-jupyter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Recommendation: Favor Creation Over Mutation

Trying to update release versions of core environment software (e.g., `r-base=4.0` to `r-base=4.1`, `python=3.6` to `python=3.9`) is often a waste compute resources, since it involves changing nearly every package in the environment and makes for a difficult solve for `conda`. It is usually far more efficacious to create separate environments for each release version you use:

**Create R 4.1.1 Kernel Environment**

```bash
# include additional packages at "..."
conda create -n r_4_1_1 r-base=4.1.1 r-irkernel ...
```

As long as the environment with Jupyter Lab has `nb_conda_kernels` installed (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/570918)), this will automatically make the new R 4.1.1 environment available as a kernel.