# math.h not found when using openmp (llvm) with sourceCpp

Tags: macos, llvm, openmp, rcpp

I am trying to use openmp in my Rcpp code and encounter some issues (Mac OS). 
Have tried googling a lot but not able to find a solution that works for me. Would appreciate if you can provide some thoughts.

Some of my setups:
1) installed llvm from home-brew
2) Makevars in ~/.R

CXX= /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang-cpp

CXXFLAGS =-I/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include

LDFLAGS=“-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib”

It looks like the LDFLAGS specified in the Makevars was ignored.
Also, when I use sourceCpp(temp.cpp), I get this error

> usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang-cpp 
>   -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include  -I"/Users/myname/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/myname/Library/R/3.2/library/RcppArmadillo/include"  -fopenmp -fPIC  -I/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -c temp.cpp -o temp.o
>
> In file included from temp.cpp:2:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/4.0.0_1/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:301:15:
>   fatal error: 'math.h' file not found
>
> ## include_next
>
> ^~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. Error in sourceCpp(paste(path2, "temp.cpp", sep = ""), verbose = TRUE,  :
>   Error 1 occurred building shared library. make: *** [temp.o] Error 1

In the temp.cpp, I have put

```
#include <math.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]



using namespace Rcpp;
```

Comment: Make sure you read all the relevant FAQ entries for OS X / macOS.  By Apple's choice it still does _not_ have openMP support but you can get it for R too if you install the right tools.  This is all documented in other places.

Comment: @Max Lau did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Xcode command line tools installed (or re-installed after upgrading the operating system)? Try running:

`xcode-select --install`

This was the solution to a similar problem that I encountered recently.

Answer (score 0):

fro macos user, update the xcode and install it, then install the devtools , it works for me.

this is indicating that the dplyr package headers couldn't be found. I just tried from source and everything works. From the armadillo issue ticket, I think one problem is not using the CRAN-provided clang and setting the appropriate path. c.f. Installing the clang7 r binary

https://github.com/rmacoslib/r-macos-clang/issues/10

https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Answer (score 0):

For macOS, the best solution is to simply [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17625368/4169943) your R version. Recent versions of R (>3.6) have resolved this issue.

See the discussion here - https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/922