# loadNamespace error loading choroplethr package in R

Tags: r, choroplethr

I'm trying to use the *county_choroplethr* function of *library(choropleth)* package in R. 
I have installed, uninstalled, and re-installed this package repeatedly, but keep getting:

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
>   versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    there is no package called ‘tibble’

In addition:

> Warning messages:  1: package ‘choroplethr’ was built under R version
>   3.2.5   2: package ‘stringr’ was built under R version 3.2.5   3: package ‘XML’ was built under R version 3.2.5   Error: package or
>   namespace load failed for ‘choroplethr’

Comment: It seems like it needs that other package called `tibble`. Maybe try installing it first? In addition seems like there are some version mismatch between your R and built packages. Maybe you updated R and didn't reinstall the packages somehow?

Comment: Thanks @KarolisKoncevičius for the suggestion. I installed tibble, and another error with a package dependency takes its place. htmlTable, backports, rprojroot, markdown, etc. Seems like a never-ending loop of dependencies. I have the latest version of RStudio, so I can't figure out with the issue may be. Thanks again for your thoughts.

Comment: R and R-studio are different things. R is the language and R-studio is an editing environment. Maybe try updating the R itself as well? This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13656699/1953718

Comment: But if the error message is changing to different packages that probably means you are moving forward. Another possibility is to simply try installing all those packages that it complains about.