# warning: package ‘grid’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, package

I get a

> warning: package ‘grid’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

but I am using R studio Version 1.0.153? I do have R 3.1.1 on my computer.

There are two warnings about,

> warning:package ‘gridExtra’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
>   warning: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.1.3

I have checked the most viewed question, learned a lot, but still not solving my issue here..

--update--the detailed console is--

> install.packages("grid")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘grid’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Comment: R and Rstudio are different. RStudio is really just an interface for running R code. Your computer is likely using your R 3.1.1 version "behind the scenes". You could check `R.Version()$version.string`. This answer might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656699/update-r-using-rstudio

Comment: When are you getting this warnings/error? What commands are you actually running?

Answer (score 1):

`grid` is a built-in package (when I do `help(package="grid")` it tells me `Priority: base`), which means it is included in every installation of R automatically. It doesn't exist on CRAN (the "Centralized R Archive Network", I think?), and can't be installed via `install.packages()`.

When I run `install.packages("grid")` I get

> install.packages("grid")
>   Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning messages:
>   1: package ‘grid’ is not available (for R Under development) 
>   2: package ‘grid’ is a base package, and should not be updated

which is entirely as expected ...

If you run `library("grid")`, it should just work. (If it doesn't you have a badly screwed-up R installation and should probably re-install ...)

Comment: thanks, I updated R to most recent, and it works. thanks.