# How to fix the issue with loading "Tidyverse" and "dplyr"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I am having trouble to load library "dplyr" and "tidyverse". I used to load them very often since today that I am getting the following error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is required
```

I tried to update my RStudio and update all packages rom tools option in RStudio. I also reinstall "rlang" package. But I am still unable to load dplyr and tidyverse. I am using R version 3.5.2 and RStudio Version 1.3.1073

I followed some threads online but none worked. Do you have any idea how I can fix the issue?

Comment: Have you tried updating the R version?

Comment: You will need to update the "rlang" package first.  The current version is 0.4.7.  In the process I would also update R to a more recent version.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I upgraded my R to latest version and then upgraded the packages. Following this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/a/17625368/7763483 and it worked.