# Everytime I upgrade R using homebrew I need to install most packages again

Tags: r, homebrew

R Packages are installed to `/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library`

Whenever I run `brew upgrade r` and the version of R changes I need to install most of the libraries again as the path of installation changes.

How do I upgrade without having to install everything back again?

Edit: I think this answers my question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r-on-windows`

Comment: The expected location after a default installation is: `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library`. Using brew is not recommended by the maintainer of the OSX branch of R. And ... everyone who makes a major version update also needs to reinstall packages, so you may just be asking one of the R-FAQ questions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but this occasionally also happens with Ruby, Python, etc. package environments.  I might be a flaw in Homebrew.

Answer (score 2):

I put `.libPaths("/Users/tim/.R/packages")` in my `~/.Rprofile` so that packages are installed to a path that doesn't disappear after a version bump.

Comment: Do you know if there is an advantage to this over setting `R_LIBS_USER` or `R_LIBS_SITE`?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on other answers by including packages from BioConductor as well as CRAN.

1. Before install: Backup current package list.

   `tmp <- installed.packages()
   installedpkgs <- as.vector(tmp[is.na(tmp[,"Priority"]), 1])
   save(installedpkgs, file="installed_old.rda")`
2. Install new version of R
3. Reload packages from CRAN

   `load("installed_old.rda")
   tmp <- installed.packages()
   installedpkgs.new <- as.vector(tmp[is.na(tmp[,"Priority"]), 1])
   missing <- setdiff(installedpkgs, installedpkgs.new)
   install.packages(missing)
   update.packages()`
4. Reload packages from BioConductor

   `chooseBioCmirror()
   biocLite()
   load("installed_old.rda")
   tmp <- installed.packages()
   installedpkgs.new <- as.vector(tmp[is.na(tmp[,"Priority"]), 1])
   missing <- setdiff(installedpkgs, installedpkgs.new)
   for (i in 1:length(missing)) biocLite(missing[i])`

Answer (score 0):

1. Save a list of your packages as an R data file

   tmp <- installed.packages()
   installedpkgs <- as.vector(tmp[is.na(tmp[,"Priority"]), 1])
   save(installedpkgs, file="installed_old.rda")
2. Install new version
3. Load the list, then download the old packages from CRAN

   oad("installed_old.rda")
   tmp <- installed.packages()
   installedpkgs.new <- as.vector(tmp[is.na(tmp[,"Priority"]), 1])
   missing <- setdiff(installedpkgs, installedpkgs.new)
   install.packages(missing)
   update.packages()