# Upgrading R using brew on OS X

Tags: r

I have had this problem once before, and I can’t figure out the best way to fix it.

I am upgrading r from v3.1.2_1 to v3.1.3 to  using `brew upgrade r`. But when I do that I lose all the libraries that I installed under v3.1.2_1. I have to install all the libraries from scratch.

The problem seems to be that brew creates two independent directory structures for two different versions of R under `/usr/local/Cellar/r`. Is there a way to install R by telling it to use the existing libraries that have been installed?

I could just copy over the files from one version to another, but I am afraid of breaking something.

Comment: Did you even change your package directory? I believe the default User package directory is "/Users/username/Library/R/3.1/library" for 3.1.x. Since the update was a small update, it shouldn't change the user directory. If the user package directory does not exist, try to create one. And check in R: `.libPaths()`.

Comment: I did not change the package directory. doing `.libpaths()` gives: `"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Everytime I upgrade R using homebrew I need to install most packages again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866834/everytime-i-upgrade-r-using-homebrew-i-need-to-install-most-packages-again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell R where to store libraries:

```
R_LIBS=~/Rlibs
```

New version of R will look for libraries in this folder. But you will still have to update libraries:

```
update.packages()
```

Details are outlined in [this post](http://zvfak.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/updating-r-but-keeping-your-installed.html). As a side matter, have a look at the [point 2.8](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html) in R FAQ, this one is for Windows but the point is fairly generic. You may be willing to keep old installations the way they are or install new libraries.

Comment: Thank you. The link to the R FAQ helped. I copied over my old packages to the new installation following the instructions there. I appreciate the point about using a custom library path in R_LIBS, but if I am not wrong that will only help with packages that are installed from that point. I am asking about packages that I have already installed (there are a lot of them) which I want to use with the new version of R.

Comment: @vyom On principle, the safest way to do it is install your packages anew into designated directory and then do the updates. If you insist on moving your packages, have a look at [this discussion](http://superuser.com/questions/474511/move-installed-r-library-to-other-directory), you can attempt to move your packages from one directory to another but I wouldn't recommend that. To save time [you could install packages via some neat loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175912/load-multiple-packages-at-once).