# Error while trying to use 'ez' library

Tags: r

I've error while trying to call `ez` library for `rAnova`, the issue that I cannot found `pbkrtest` package while I executed with success `install.packages("ez")`. `library(ez)` return to me the following error :

```
 Error in loadNamespace (j <- i [[1L]], c (lib.loc, .libPaths ()) = vI VERSIONCHECK [[j]]):   no package named 'pbkrtest' is found
    In addition: Warning message: package 'ez' was compiled with version 3.2.5 R         Error: loading the package or namespace failed for 'ez'
```

How can I properly use this library ? Thanks

EDIT : `Sessioninfo()`

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
Error in x[["Version"]] : index out of limits
De plus : Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  The file DESCRIPTION  of the package 'digest' is missing or incorrect
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  The file DESCRIPTION  of the package 'nlme' is missing or incorrect
```

EDIT 2: `Sessioninfo()` after restarting machine and R

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] MASS_7.3-45     Matrix_1.2-7.1  tools_3.2.2     mgcv_1.8-15    
[5] nnet_7.3-12     nlme_3.1-121    grid_3.2.2      lattice_0.20-34
```

but still the same error (above) when tape library(ez).

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("pbkrtest")`?

Comment: Yes : Warning message: package ‘pbkrtest’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2) Is it linked to the version ?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error. Just a simple `install.packages("ez");library(ez)` worked fine for me. I'm running R 3.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.5. It might be helpful to post your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Thanks, please take a look on the EDIT.

Comment: That error in your `sessionInfo()` seems pretty weird, I've never seen that before. Maybe you could do a google search for those error messages? I don't know french, so I'm not sure what they mean. Have you tried restarting your R session?

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware about langague. I tried to translate it. EDIT 2 for sessionInfo() after restarting R. I think I should change R version but not sure.

Comment: Have you tried updating R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that was a question of R version. As noticed in the error and as I understood 'ez' was compiled with version 3.2.5 R. So now i'm under 3.3.1 and I intalled EZ with success and can load the library and use the function. The more complicated is to reinstall R and all packages that seems painful, but thanks to this [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r)  that allow me to store all my packages in a temp folder and to reinstall them in the newest version

For information if it could help someone else, my Sessioninfo() returns :

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ez_4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7        magrittr_1.5       splines_3.3.1      MASS_7.3-45        munsell_0.4.3     
 [6] colorspace_1.2-6   lattice_0.20-33    minqa_1.2.4        stringr_1.1.0      car_2.1-3         
[11] plyr_1.8.4         tools_3.3.1        nnet_7.3-12        parallel_3.3.1     pbkrtest_0.4-6    
[16] grid_3.3.1         nlme_3.1-128       gtable_0.2.0       mgcv_1.8-12        quantreg_5.29     
[21] MatrixModels_0.4-1 lme4_1.1-12        Matrix_1.2-6       nloptr_1.0.4       reshape2_1.4.1    
[26] ggplot2_2.1.0      stringi_1.1.2      scales_0.4.0       SparseM_1.72      
>
```