# Error installing quantmod in RStudio Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, rstudio, quantmod, rstudio-server

I have encountered problem installing quantmod in my RStudio Ubuntu VM, which I need help in

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code or error messages on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/205233)

Comment: Are you *actually* running R-2.14.0?

Answer (score 0):

Installation of `quantmod` need `curl` & `TTR` packages. You should do something like this.

```
install.packages("curl")
install.packages("TTR"")
install.packages("quantmod")
```

Comment: > install.packages("curl")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/rstudio/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘curl’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)

How do I continue from here?

Comment: You need to upgrade R. Install New From Scratch or Upgrade existing one.. This question might help you in Upgrading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r

Comment: I tried to install curl and TTR packages it still gives me an error, will have to update R version. But the link given too many comments to follow-up, any short and sweet remedy to my current problem to recommend?