# ERROR: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I am getting this error while running an  rmarkdown file.

```
pandoc.exe: out of memory
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m - 
RTS Missing_StatisAna.utf8.md --to html4 --from 
markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash -- 
output Missing_StatisAna.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self- 
contained --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 -- 
variable toc_float=1 --variable toc_selectors=h1,h2 --variable 
toc_collapsed=1 --variable toc_smooth_scroll=1 --variable toc_print=1 -- 
template "C:\Users\bella~1\DOCUME~1\R\WIN- 
LI~1\3.4\RMARKD~1\rmd\h\DEFAUL~1.HTM" --highlight-style espresso --number- 
sections --variable "theme:united" --include-in-header 
 "C:\Users\bella~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpO6fyLX\rmarkdown- 
 str4f7818b95d1e.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax- 
url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS- 
MML_HTMLorMML" --variable code_folding=hide --variable code_menu=1' had 
status 1 
Execution halted
```

If anybody has resolved this error or have an idea, please let me know.

Many Thanks

Comment: `pandoc.exe: out of memory`, looks suspicious! what did you do in your rmd file?

Comment: Well, I am imputing the missing value with multiple packages like MICE, Miss Forrest and then using logistic regression to the imputed dataset. Takes 1 hour to run because of the long calculation.

It looks like the a memory issue but this whole process is of limited use if the entire analysis runs but the document can't be output.  If anyone has any ideas on how to deal with memory issues in the final step of pandoc conversion or can point me to where to look for this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any `install.packages(*)` in your code?

Comment: NO. I directly attached to the library().

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1152

Comment: And, of course, [update R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r) and your packages with `update.packages()`.

Comment: Thanks But nothing changed :(