# How to update all packages for a new R version quickly and easily?

Tags: r, cran

Suppose I have R version 3.x.x installed, and I upgrade to version 4.x.x, is there any quick/easy way to install all the new versions of the libraries I had installed?

Please assume all the packages are on CRAN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Painless way to install a new version of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r)

Comment: 1) The call to `update.packages()` will always do that for you.  2) In the special case of an R major version change, you can set option `checkBuilt=TRUE` which triggers a reinstallation even if the package did not change at CRAN but because you moved R versions.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks Dirk. Should I provide a vector of package names to `update.packages()` or does it figure that out?

Comment: It takes the existing ones as given, see `help(update.packages())`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't know if this is quick and easy, but I think the `pacman` package can be useful.

1. Under the previous version, use `pacman::p_lib()` to return a vector of your installed packages, and save them onto disk use `saveRDS()`.

For instance,

```
mypks <- pacman::p_lib()
saveRDS(mypks, "~/mypks.rds")
```

2. Update R.
3. Import the vector from step 1 using `readRDS()` and run `install.packages()` with the object.

For instance,

```
mypks <- readRDS("~/mypks.rds")
install.packages(mypks)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was quick and painless. I ended up using a lazier version of your approach, which I noted below for future reference

Answer (score 12):

Following works for me:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer: this needs nothing but base R functionality. (As my earlier comment from 2021 already mentioned.)

Answer (score 4):

#### Step 1

Run this in the **previous** R installation:

```
# install.packages("pacman")
library(pacman)
dput(pacman::p_lib())
```

Copy the output to clipboard.

#### Step 2

Open your **new** R version, paste the output from the previous step in place of `***paste output here***`:

```
vector_of_packages <- ***paste output here***
install.packages(vector_of_packages)
```

Notes:

- This is just a lazier way of doing what [@Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66450637/5783745) suggests.

Answer (score 3):

The latest versions of RStudio have an Update option next to the list of packages installed under the Packages tab.

Comment: That answer is somewhere between 'irrelevant' (as R itself always had `update.packages()` as a function) and 'misleading'.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily,

`update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)`

works if you just `mv` or

```
cd oldlibdir
tar -cf . -| (cd newdir; tar -xf -)
```

from the shell and then run it from the R console in the new version (usually). The problem with having to save a vector of installed R packages from within your previous version to feed to `update.packages` is that automatic software package upgrades (`pkg, apr, rpm`) will upgrade R before you get a chance

I always `pkg lock` R so it only gets upgraded when I explicitly invoke an R software upgrade.

Comment: Hello,

I recently upgraded R 4.3.3 on debian stable via backports. Now, if for instance I open an R session and I do library(ggplot2), I do not get a warning that the library was built under the previous R version (actually I do not get any such warning for any library). 
Two questions then:
1) do I still need to reinstall all the user-installed packages?
2) any way to do that with the pak library instead of base R and check.Built=T? I find pak nicer and more performant.

Many thanks!