# R: Update Packages after New Release Using Pak

Tags: r, pak

When a new R version is released (I am on Debian Linux), I usually run the command

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

like suggested here

[How to update all packages for a new R version quickly and easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450454/how-to-update-all-packages-for-a-new-r-version-quickly-and-easily/77255130#77255130)

I also like very much pak

https://pak.r-lib.org/dev/index.html

to install/update packages, but I do not know whay is the equivalent of

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

in pak. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks