# Elegant way to recover R packages after a update

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, installr

Recently my package manager updated R automatically to the newest version 4.10 (well, i give the permission so is my fault), whenever this happens the packages from the older version are lost. But i was wondering if there is elegant way to recover all the packages from the older version.

If this is not possible, what is the best practice?

I'm familiar with the discussion in [Painless way to install a new version of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r), but the discussion is how avoid this problem, and i'm new user of Ubuntu (version 20.04), so i'm still learning how manage packages.

Comment: Have you tried copying the package folders from R 4.0.X folder to R 4.1.0 folder?

Comment: I didn't, since i don't know if this is a good practice. I'm afraid if this break some tree of package.